# Negative message count on ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

In ActiveMQ Artemis 2.14.0 what does it mean if I see a negative message count in the web console? The server recently crashed from high heap usage. I'm trying to solve that. I restarted Artemis but I can't find anything in the docs about negative message counts.

Comment: artemis version: 2.14.0, hawtio version: 1.5.12, jolokia version: 1.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative message count is almost always the result of a bug or perhaps the corruption of internal state due to a JVM issue (e.g. running out of heap). There's no documentation on it because it shouldn't happen. If you encounter this situation during normal operation file a bug report in the [ActiveMQ Artemis Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS). Please include a full description of the use-case and a reproducer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just in case somebody else has this problem and is trying to solve it; After a crash of our host system which also caused the Artemis-VM to fall down, we had -120 messages in queue (we are running ActiveMQ Artemis **2.15.0**).

I managed to solve this bug by purging the queue in the Web UI and restarting the service. We didn't lose a single message and the counter is now positive (or zero) :)

Maybe this will help you too. Another idea would've been a deletion of the queue, because it'll be recreated after a restart as long as it is defined in the broker.xml. Im pretty certain, this would've helped as well.